# How can I implement multiple ViewModel types to use the same Action for get and posts?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am building a cms, on the edit screen for a section you can edit multiple types of pages, the urls need to remain nutral, like this:

foobar.com/edit/section/my-content-page-name
foobar.com/edit/section/my-gallery-page-name
foobar.com/edit/section/my-blog-page-name

In this scenario the Index action is used for both gets and posts.

At the moment I have one massive ViewModel, that encompasses all the data required across all page types.

I feel this is quite wrong and, makes an ugly solution for deciding what type of page update on the post.

How can I keep the Action the same but use it with different strongly type ViewModels?

Is this even possible?

```
public ActionResult Index(string page)
    {
        var model = _pageManager.GetSection(page, SelectedSite);
        return View(model.PageType, model);

        // renders appropriate View based on page type.

    }

    [Transaction]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Index(SectionIndexViewModel model)
    {
        // all page types post back to same action to update content etc.
        // at this point SectionIndexViewModel is getting bloated with properties because it must cater for ALL page types data.

        var action = Request["action"] ?? "";

        // currently use this to determine what event has been triggered 
        switch (action.ToLower())
        {
         // then goes to update the appropriate page, blog or gallery
         // etc.
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Could you show your current code so that we can see why is it inappropriate and how it could be improved?

Comment: This just feels dirty, as you are using one action for different types of pages. I would say that you need to create an advanced routing, that routes based on what is in your URL to the appropriate controllers and action (especially if you creating different types of pages).

Comment: yup, its already got some pretty mad routing in. the trick comes in with validation errors, if i am at a different action i start loosing the context of the data in relation to the validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this with some MVC basics that I had forgotten about.

The routing remains as per the defaults.

For each ViewModel type I delivered an extra hidden field in the form, with the type of the page/content/ViewModel eg: Content Page, or Blog Page etc.

In the Post action, I check the type of the page from this hidden field.

Then use `TryUpdateModel` using the expected ViewModel type for that page type.

And the rest is straight forward.

Pretty basic stuff really.

Answer (score 0):

> all page types post back to same action to update content etc.

There is your problem. The same action should not handle all post backs. Create one controller per feature (content, gallery, blog). It's how MVC is intended to be used.

Single Responsibility Principle do also apply to controllers.

You can even move the controllers to class libraries to get plugin like architecture for your CMS. I've described how here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/griffin-mvccontrib-the-plugin-system/